# dialog-box not loading a view in server after publishing the project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog

Here i am trying to load a partial view inside a dialog-box using jquery. This is my code:

```
 $('#newdialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 900,
            top: 76,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Modify Add image',
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                //Load the CreateAlbumPartial action which will return 
                // the partial view _CreateAlbumPartial
                // alert(idimg);
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("GridView1","LandingSetting")");
            },
            buttons: false,
            //            {
            //                "Close": function () {
            //                    $(this).dialog("close");
            //                }
            //            },
            position: {
                my: 'top',
                at: 'top',
                of: $('.maindiv')
            }

        });
```

My View Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GridView";
    Layout = null;
}
<h2>
</h2>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="HOME" style="overflow: auto; height: 560px; width: 880px; background-color: #E0E0E0;
                    color: White;">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "adform" }))
                    {
                        if (Model.Count == 0)
                        {

                        <h1 align="center">
                            Sorry No Ads Found! Please Add some ads.</h1>
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                @{
                            int crow = 1;
                            foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                    <td>
                                        <ul style="list-style: none;">
                                            <li>
                                                <img src="@item.banner" width="250" height="170" />
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <input id="@item.banner" type="radio" name="one" value="@item.banner" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                if (crow % 2 == 0)
                                {                                                    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 285px; height: 50px">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                                crow++;

                            }

                                }
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This code **works fine in the localhost**.But when I **publish my project** and run it on a server, the **dialog box opens but the parial view is not loading** in it.What am i doing wrong? can anyone help.Thanks

**Edit: The jquery code is on my main view which has a layout page reference as well as the required jquery reference. In that page if i click a button, the dialog box should open and the above mentioned view should load in it.**

Comment: Which errors do you receive in javascript?

Comment: no errors are coming...it only opens a blank dialog box

Comment: Can you post your partial view code

Comment: Try removing the HTML and body tags. Do you have a shared layout?

Comment: The partial view code you have shown doesn't look very *partial*. That's a full blown HTML page.

Comment: yes i have a shared layout but for this view i don't want to use it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yeah its a normal view. But is it going to create a problem after publishing the project?

Comment: Then why do you call it a *partial*? Do you know what a partial view is? Also if this is your main view where are your script definitions? Do you have a _Layout?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yeah i do know what a partial view is. But this is just a simple view which just shows some photos and radio buttons to select them. Anyhow i will change the title of my question

Comment: Alright, now what about the other questions I asked? If this is your main view where are your script definitions? Do you have a _Layout? In the example you have shown I don't see where have you included jquery, jquery-ui and the custom script you have shown.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i have added an edit in my question...the view which i have shown is not my main view..in my main view i have all the necessary references...do it need to add the references here also?? anyhow it is working properly before publishing the project

Comment: I don't understand why does the view you have shown contains `<html>` and `<body>` tags and yet you have another main view. I suspect that you end up with some very broken markup in the browser.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i removed everything except the <table> and its contents but still it is not working...as a matter of fact none of the dialog boxes are showing their respective views..some of those views have nothing but submit button in them

Comment: You are not answering my questions, so it is hard to help. Can you send me a sample project exhibiting the behavior? I you don't want to show your code I don't see how I can help.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i will send you the sample project...but its gonna take some time as i would have to make some necessary adjustments..is it ok with you..can i send it to your mail??

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is caused by Cross Domain Request. If your action url leads to a different host (possibly even a subdomain) you will have an error in your console stating you cannot make such requests. Anyway if your console does output something let us know.

Otherwise try removing the doctype, html, head, body etc. tags from the partial view, you already have those on your page no need to create a bad nesting situation.